# How to map the localhost path for magento 2 index file, to a domain name

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.5

I have created a magento 2 setup and currently accessing the site by punching the whole url like

> localhost\bla\bla\bla.....\magento-root-directory\

But I would like it to be

> localhost\www.xyz.com

How to achieve the same.

Comment: You can't have domain.com/[some_path]/ set in Magento as 'Base Url'.  After [some_path] you'd like to have /frontName/controller/action/. That's the same to localhost/www.qwerty.com/ Better define virtual hosts in webserver conf.

Comment: What's your local environment?

Comment: Env : centos 6, php 5.6, apache  2.2.15 , mysql 5.6.35

Answer (score 0):

I am waiting for about 2 hours for an answer but as no one posted so am giving my answer. Not sure if it's a proper way to do it or it's a hack but it should work.
Create a folder in htdocs named xyz.com and create an index.php file in it. Open that file and write this code.

```
<?php
$url ='url to to your magento ';
header('Location: '.$url);
```